# Hibernate setter changes not related column

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, setter

Hi I am trying to update multiple records in database if they pass through if statement. I want to update one column but when I do it updates other column too.

TABLE: Appointments

id | Cancelled | Time | Doctor_id

Code:

```
public void cancelDoctorsAppoitmentsByDateBetweenTimeInterval(int idDoctor, Date date, Time from, Time to){
        from = new java.sql.Time((long) (from.getTime() - 1.14e+6));
        List<Appointment> appointments = getDoctorsAppointmentsByDate(idDoctor, date);
        for(Appointment appointment : appointments) {
            if(appointment.getDate().equals(date) && appointment.getTime().after(from) && appointment.getTime().before(to)
                    && !appointment.isCanceled()){

                Appointment appointmentToUpdate = currentSession().find(Appointment.class, appointment.getId());
                appointmentToUpdate.setCanceled(true);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I set cancelled to true. Database updates also column Time (it sets 1 hour sooner than it was previously). Why does this happen?